# Creating an Array Rotation

Tags: modifiers

I'm having trouble creating a Rotational Array. First I transform the object, a UV Sphere, along the Y axis to the radius I want the array to have. I add an Empty at the world origin. I choose the UV Sphere, and start to add an Array Modifier. I set the offset to 0,0,0. The number of copies I set to 8. I enable Object Offset and choose the Empty. And this is where the problem starts. I had planed to then rotate the Empty by 45 degrees, but before I can do that 8 copies of the UV Sphere appear in a straight line with the first copy centered on the vertical axis of the Empty. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This seems only to work when the sphere does not have a transformation on it. Try moving the sphere in edit mode instead of in object mode.

Answer (score 2):

The array object need to be away from its origin.
un-tick Relative offset, tick object offset in the Array modifier tab.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have an *Array* going around a rotation you need to create a *Curve* that it can follow. For example you add a *Circle*.  On your *Array* *Modifier* you only set the *Count* and enable the *Relative Offset* the other fields stay at default. Now you add a second *Modifier* which is called *Curve* and select the added *Circle* as *Object*.

Here is an example file:
[image]